# Отрисовка разных картинок в зависимости от URL

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите,как реализовать,чтобы в зависимости от юрл на который переходит человек менялась всего лишь одна картинка на другую.

Answer (score 2):

Можно проверять uri запроса с помощью $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] и в зависимости от значения отдавать нужную картинку

Answer (score 2):

берешь адрес (window.location.href), проверяешь, если проходит по условию тянешь картинку